# Neo4j: One to one relationship update

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Currently I have two label types:

- User
- Organization

A User works in an organization. I am trying to update this relationship when the organization changes. I came up with a solution that doesn't satisfy me. First I delete the current relationship with the previous node and then I create the relationship again with the new organization. This is how it logically works in RDBMS but on graph databases should be more easily.

```
       MATCH (user:User)
       WHERE id(user) = $id
       SET user = $props

       WITH user
       OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[ro:WORKS_IN]->(organization:Organization)
       DELETE ro

       WITH user
       MATCH (organization:Organization {name: 'Ebay'})
       CREATE (user)-[:WORKS_IN]->(organization)

       RETURN user , organization
```

I need to come up with a more elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: Hi @Diego-Gallegos! If this one of the answers has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I don't think there's very much here you can change to make this less verbose. The most I can think of right now is leaving off the variable and type from the :WORKS_IN relationship pattern (but only if it's okay to remove all :WORKS_IN relationships from a :User node, assuming they are all :Organization nodes at the other end:

```
   MATCH (user:User)
   WHERE id(user) = $id
   SET user = $props

   WITH user
   OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[ro:WORKS_IN]->()
   DELETE ro

   WITH user
   MATCH (organization:Organization {name: 'Ebay'})
   CREATE (user)-[:WORKS_IN]->(organization)

   RETURN user , organization
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) and use the graph refactoring procedure `apoc.refactor.to` to change the end node. The docs says:

> `call apoc.refactor.to(rel, endNode)`: redirect relationship to use new
>   end-node.